# Is there any way to include a comment in a referenced cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two Excel spreadsheets:

1. The master sheet which has tables of data
2. A second sheet which references certain cells from the master sheet in order to collate certain data.

I wanted to know if there’s a way to be able to have the referenced cells also copy the comment on the master sheet over?

Comment: There is no way for that with standard worksheet functions. You need to use macros for that.